# How to 'lock' scroll to div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've set up a scrolling website (essentially a parallax-styled page, without the parallax effects) where each "page" is just a div that takes up 100% of the screen. But I need some sort of mechanism to 'lock' the scroll into the correct position so that the div will align properly with the user's browser.

If you need an example, Flickr's splash page does this perfectly.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's a link to the site I'm working on. The code's a bit messy, and some images aren't loading (since they're not hosted yet) but it's there to give you a rough idea of how the site functions.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/99QjJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to build a fast solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/7pYhB/3/)

It prevents the normal scrolling and scrolls just to the appropriate offset of the divs:

```
if(!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    currentDiv = (scrollDirection == "down" ? currentDiv + 1 : currentDiv - 1)
    $("html,body").animate({
        "scrollTop":offsets[currentDiv]
    },{queue:true,duration:1000,complete:function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
             scrolling = false;
         },200);
    }});
```

It's no complete solution but I think this would work.
Another idea would be using one of the thousands of jQuery plugins which make the page scrollable via the arrow keys. I think if each of the divs fits the entire screen size there's no actual need for scrolling "in between".

Comment: I implemented the code, but for some reason I'm getting nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So you're doing a 'one page' site, correct? Can't you use anchor tags on each element you want to jump to?

You can animate it to make it look pretty with [this](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll) nice jQuery plugin